# setTag() on button click for multiple value

Tags: android, tags

```
        dater.setText(theday);
        dater.setTag(1, theday);
        dater.setTag(2, theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);

        dater.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                notification(date_txt);
                String day = v.getTag(1).toString();
                date_txt.setText(day);
            }
        });
```

im doing set tag for a textview im doing it using settag(int key object tag); and settag(key) but im getting error which i cant figure out any ideas on this thank you

Comment: i got where i made a mistake i read in a post that the key should be in resource or something like that so what i did is i tried to change the key to something like this R.id.date and it worked i will try to get the whole date i hope i will still work..lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dater.setText(theday);
   List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
   data.add(theday);
   data.add(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);
    dater.setTag(data);


    dater.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            notification(date_txt);
            ViewHold holder=v.getTag
            String day = ((List<String>)v.getTag()).get(1).toString();
            date_txt.setText(day);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

this answer in very usefull

```
textView.setTag(new HoldsTwoObjs(obj1, obj2));
HoldsTwoObjs isTagClass=(HoldsTwoObjs)textView.getTag();
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27528427/1140304

Answer (score 0):

The key that you use in `settag(int key object tag);` should be an `id` declared in your resources.

According to the documentation

```
Sets a tag associated with this view and a key. A tag can be used to mark a view in its
hierarchy and does not have to be unique within the hierarchy. Tags can also be used to
store data within a view without resorting to another data structure. **The specified key 
should be an id declared in the resources of the application to ensure it is unique (see 
the ID resource type). Keys identified as belonging to the Android framework or not 
associated with any package will cause an IllegalArgumentException to be thrown.**
```

Comment: that is what i did as i stated in my comment on top you were a bit late mate thank you anyway for the effort