# How to set multiple tags for an object in android

Tags: android

**My research** I have found that I need to use below methodology

```
textView.setTag(1,object1);
textView.setTag(2,object2);
```

**What i tried::**

- i tried to pass a `list` in place of `object` but couldn't get it to
  work.
- I understand it has to be an object, if so how to make that object.
  any samples would help

Comment: I think you should give some more information about why you need to do this. There are multiple way to handle cases like this in a more organized architecture, without tags. Can you be more precise and give some more information about the use case you are trying to implement?

Comment: waht kind of error do you get if you use textView.setTag(1,object1);
textView.setTag(2,object2);?

Comment: the object has to be any value, for example it could be `textView.setTag(1,"first");` or `textView.setTag(1,1);`. So answer depends on, what exactly you want to achieve from this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If need to add multiple tag into one view the you have to define the id for every tag in string.xml file like:

```
<item type="id" name="section"/>
  <item type="id" name="hide_show"/>
```

after adding the key you can use these keys in java file like below :

```
rowView.setTag(R.id.section,mSectionList.get(position));
rowView.setTag(R.id.hide_show,"close");
```

this will set the tag. At the time of getting tag you need to typecast the object which originally you set like :

```
Section mSection=(Section)rowView.getTag(R.id.section);
String isOpen=(String)rowView.getTag(R.id.hide_show);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have two tags on an object, you should just make a class that holds those two objects, then set that as the tag.

For example: `textView.setTag(new HoldsTwoObjs(obj1, obj2))`;